# float of large number returning as incorrect value

Tags: objective-c

```
float testFloat = 40999838;
```

I put in a breakpoint, and then it shows it as `40999840`, 2 numbers higher than it should be.

Does anybody know why this is happening, and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 1):

`float` can't store that many significant digits so the value is assigned the closest possible value that it can.

Use `double` and your problem will go away since `double` can store more significant digits.

Comment: I'm actually using it inside a CGPoint. How would I go about this?

Comment: Why would you have such a large value inside of `CGPoint`? You are never going to need to reference a point that large.

Comment: You need something with `double`. Perhaps you can use `CLLocation`.